# Spring Boot 3.0 compatibility with Spring Cloud AWS pre 3.0.0 / AWS SDK V1

Tags: spring-boot, aws-sdk, spring-cloud

Is it possible to use Spring Boot 3.0 with versions of Spring Cloud AWS prior to 3.0?  Or is the upgrade to Spring Cloud AWS 3.0 a requirement of the migration to Spring Boot 3.0?

Spring Cloud AWS 3.0 is built on AWS SDK V2.  Does this mean if we are already using Spring Cloud AWS and we update to Boot 3.0 then we will need to upgrade to Spring Cloud AWS 3.0 and by extension to AWS SDK V2 as well?

Comment: Yes, that is correct